# Virtualbox gives Error code: 0x000000C4 with Windows 8.1 or 2012

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8.1, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

Trying to boot Windows 8.1 or Windows server 2012, either a previously installed VM or booting from CS/ISO on virtualbox gives Error code: 0x000000C4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This solution fixed the problem for me:

http://4sysops.com/forums/topic/windows-server-2012-r2-on-virtual-box-error-0x000000c4/

You need to set a parameter in virtualbox to enable a certain CPU instruction. [vmname] should be replaced with the name of the affected VM without square brackets.

Windows:

```
"c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" setextradata [vmname] VBoxInternal/CPUM/CMPXCHG16B 1
```

Mac, Linux:

```
VBoxManage setextradata [vmname] VBoxInternal/CPUM/CMPXCHG16B 1
```

Comment: Command `VBoxManage setextradata [vmname] VBoxInternal/CPUM/CMPXCHG16B 1` works also under Ubuntu (14.04), vbox 4.2.26

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, and it's also possible to [set `CMPXCHG16B` globally](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/11899):

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" setextradata global VBoxInternal/CPUM/CMPXCHG16B 1
```

However I also had to go into the BIOS and change the `Memory Protection` setting from `Disabled` to `Enabled` before the issue went away.